# Finding median without using a sort function

Tags: python, median

As a homework assignment I have to write a script which finds the median of 3 given numbers without using a standard sort function of Python.

This is my first week in class and my first programming experience so I find it very difficult to get any further than I am right now.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def med3(a,b,c):
    list = [a, b, c]
    newlist = []
    if list:
        minimum = list[0]
        for x in list:
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
                newlist.append(minimum)
                list.remove(minimum)
            elif x >= minimum:
                newlist.append(x)
                list.remove(x)

    return newlist[1]
```

This seems to do the trick, but only for the first two entries of the list. The loop doesn't include the third entry.

How can I make the script include all three entries?

Thanks in advance!
Sander

Comment: Too much work. Define what "median" means in the context of 3 numbers without using loops and lists.

Comment: You have a lot of code there that really isn't needed. Also since this is homework, its for you to figure out, not for us to do it for you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have many unnecessary steps here. For example, `if list:` is unnecessary: you've just defined the list. But in general you don't need lists or loops. Hint: you can do this using three `if` statements that each use an `or`.

Comment: I would suggest to find out a technique to find the median of 3 given numbers _in your head_. Write down this technique in English as if giving a recipe to someone else. Finally code this technique using a programming language. (Call your text a _pseudocode_ and you're a real programmer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`sum([a, b, c]) - min(a, b, c) - max(a, b, c)` - no sorting!

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list in-place while looping over it, which has consequences for what elements you see:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in numbers:
...     if i == 2: numbers.remove(i)
...     print i
... 
1
2
```

Note how `3` is never printed; by removing the second entry in the list, we've shortened it by one element and the loop finds the list exhausted early.

Note that you don't *need* to loop over the items, a few simple comparisons will tell you what item is the median if you think about it for a second. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of simpler ways to go about this, but as for your approach:

You're modifying `list` inside of your loop. Don't do that. :)

In your case, you should be removing elements from newlist:

```
def med3(a,b,c):
    list = [a, b, c]
    newlist = []
    if list:
        minimum = list[0]
        for x in list:
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
                newlist.pop()
                newlist.append(minimum)
            elif x >= minimum:
                newlist.append(x)
    return newlist[1]
```

But as an exercise, you might want to think about a few things:

- Why are you putting the elements in a list and looping over them? What advantage does this have over comparing a,b,c with simply if statements?
- Why the `if list:`?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do it:

```
def medianFast(a, b, c):
    if a > b:
        if b > c: 
            return b
        elif a > c:
            return c
        else:
            return a
    else:
        if b < c: 
            return b
        elif a > c:
            return a
        else:
            return c
```

Guarantees you 3 comparisons at the worst case and 2 comparisons in the best case. 2,5 comparisons in average.

Using [ternary conditional](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) we can write it shorter as:

```
def medianTernary(a, b, c):
    return (b if b > c else (c if a > c else a)) if a > b else (b if b < c else (a if a > c else c))
```

If you could use sorting you would have the shortest version:

```
def medianSorted(a, b, c):
    return sorted([a, b, c])[1]
```